# Wipe a database file in iOS

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I need to wipe the sqLite database file in an iOS app that I am developing. Does anyone know how to do it ? I am very new with iOS and nothing really clear found till now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can simply delete it and then recreate it. To delete it, reference the [Creating and Deleting Items](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-SW28) of the `NSFileManager` class reference. E.g. `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];`. You can alternatively (if you need to keep the table structures) delete the rows from the individual tables and then execute the SQL `vacuum` command.

Comment: If you really want to start fresh, simply delete and reinstall the app.

Comment: Hi Rob. And how do I recreate the database with the same data that was wiped? Is this even possible? Thanks in advance